# Stack Overflow Error caused by Software keyboard using InputMethodManager

Tags: android, inputmethodmanager

I'm trying to show/hide the soft keyboard manually inside the in my activities for the edit text view on focus,
but on some device, it's showing `sys/err` and causes crash or ANR in my app with following stack traces

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.beginBatchEdit(InputConnectionWrapper.java:106)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:398)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and this some times

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getSelectedText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:54)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.getSelectedText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:54)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:241)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Code to show/hide the soft keyboard manually :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    mUserPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            mUserPassword.setSelection(mUserPassword.getText().length());
            mUserPassword.setSelection(mUserPassword.getText().length());
            if (hasFocus){
                mUserPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                mUserPassword.setHint("");
            } else {
                mUserPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                mUserPassword.setHint(getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.sign_in_hint));
            }
        }
    });

    mUserPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 0){
                mShowPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mShowPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    mUserPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                if (validateFields(mUserPassword.getText().toString().trim())){
                    showWrong(false);
                    mPresenter.userLogin(mUserEmail,encodeToBase64(mUserPassword.getText().toString().trim()));
                } else {
                    showWrong(true);
                }
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

Layout code example :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.my.app.example.customizeviews.Lato_Bold_TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="@string/sign_in_header"
    android:textColor="@color/header"
    android:id="@+id/header"/>

<com.my.app.example.customizeviews.Lato_Regular_TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
    android:text="@string/sign_in_sub_header"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:textColor="@color/subHeader"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <com.my.app.example.customizeviews.Lato_Regular_EditTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:id="@+id/userPassword"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/sign_in_hint"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@color/transparent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/showPassword"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_unpressed"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextUnderline"
        android:background="@color/editTextBottomColor"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.my.app.example.customizeviews.Lato_Regular_TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
    android:text="@string/sign_in_forgot_password"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:textColor="@color/hintColor"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/password"/>

<com.my.app.example.customizeviews.Lato_Regular_TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sign_in_wrong_password"
    android:textColor="@color/wrongText"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:id="@+id/wrongPassword"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/password"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/signingUser"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:paddingTop="14dp"
    android:paddingBottom="14dp">

    <com.my.app.example.customizeviews.Lato_Bold_TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_menu_next"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_back_dark"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is this device problem? How to solve this error?

Comment: add you edittext listener code

Comment: @RajasekaranM added

Comment: StackOverflowError will happen when method called recursively but I don't see any method here like that

Comment: @Sam why? what condition taking it to the infinite loop?

Comment: Are you having too many nested layouts? or some drawable file resource in your XML which has larger file size?

Comment: @Sam some part of layout edited in the question

Comment: try adding this to your manifest file : `android:largeHeap="true"` and check in device which you are getting the error (in the application tag)

Comment: @Sam still happening the same

Answer (score 0):

> You can also specify the input type in the XML file,
>       There is no need to implement the setOnFocusChangeListener listener.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

> Add below dependency in gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```